# I'm trying to copy the values of a variable to clipboard from my password generator but it doesn't work

Tags: bash, scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "How many characters? 
read length

pass=sudo head /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9\!\"#$\@\&\%\?' | head -c$length
sleep 1
echo "$pass"

echo $pass | xclip -sel c
```

It works if I change out `$pass` with `$length` but that's not what I want to copy to the clipboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*So many things to look at, but assuming your initial question is about saving the output of a command as a variable.*

---

To save the output (STDOUT) of some command or pipeline as a variable, you need to use command substitution (`$()`):

```
pass=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9\!\"#$\@\&\%\?' | head -c "$length")
```

I have made two changes:

- you don't need to be `root` to read the `/dev/urandom` file, so I've dropped `sudo`
- always quote variable expansions (unless you know what you're doing);  I've quoted `$length`

---

Also, `read` can show a prompt string (see `-p` option), you don't need to use `echo`:

```
read -p 'How many characters?' length
```

Comment: I'm still a beginner at this stuff so that echo stuff is what we have learned at school. Aside from that it seems the problem was fixed with the command substitution.

Comment: So if command substitution isn't there it doesn't save the output to the variable but echo "$pass" worked in showing the value, why is that?

Comment: @Eddie What did `echo $pass` show? Without command substitution, the code syntax you've used originally would show you error(s).